# Python code to create subscriptions in Azure

Tags: python, azure

**Is it possible to create azure subscription using python code? If possible, how?**

I'm trying to find some thing like this:

```
def create_subscriptions():
    response = client.create_subscriptions(
        ------------------,
        ------------------
    )
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is python SDK [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-subscription/azure/mgmt/subscription/operations/subscription_factory_operations.py) can be used to create the subscription.

   First, you need to install the package using `pip install azure-mgmt`

   Then try to call it to create subscription.
2. You can also call this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptionfactory/createsubscriptioninenrollmentaccount) in python to create subscription.

Comment: More precisely, you need the package azure-mgmt-subscription. See this test: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/41e37c8a10876db40697a63e828ed7cafc19c7d6/azure-mgmt-subscription/tests/test_mgmt_subscription.py

Comment: @cbare Wrong kind of subscription, mate. The question is about a subscription as a service account on Azure, not a message queue subscription.

Comment: @LaurentMazuel, are there any recent examples for creating Azure Subscriptions using Python?

Comment: I believe it's not supported anymore, I would ask https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues for details or create an Azure support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You should use the REST API provided by Azure to do so. I do not believe this has been abstracted into the SDK already (although @Ivan Yang indicates differently).

Basically it boils down to doing this REST request for your enrollment account:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts/747ddfe5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Subscription/createSubscription?api-version=2018-03-01-preview

{
  "displayName": "Dev Team Subscription",
  "offerType": "MS-AZR-0017P",
  "owners": [
    {
      "objectId": ""
    },
    {
      "objectId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

More documentation on how to do so can be found at the MSFT blog on it. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest

Comment: Yes, the SDK is available as Ivan said (I work in the Python SDK team at MS)